# How to avoid getting unchecked cast warning when retrieving Serializable object from Bundle

Tags: java, android

In my application I have an activity that has a member variable named `mSelectedContacts` of type `HashSet<Integer>`, which is part of the activity state, so I am saving it in `onSaveInstanceState()` like this

```
public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    savedInstanceState.putSerializable(STATE_SELECTED_CONTACTS, mSelectedContacts);
    super.onSaveInstanceState(savedInstanceState);
}
```

and when recreating the activity, I am getting the stored Hashset like this.

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    if (savedInstanceState != null &&
            savedInstanceState.containsKey(STATE_SELECTED_CONTACTS)) {
        mSelectedContacts = (HashSet<Integer>)
                savedInstanceState.getSerializable(STATE_SELECTED_CONTACTS);
    } else
        mSelectedContacts = new HashSet<Integer>();
    ...
```

Now this works fine, but it generates a unchecked cast warning (from java.io.serializable to java.lang.Integer). Is there some other way to save a serializable object into a bundle and then retrieve it without getting this warning? (other than suppressing it of course :-))

Comment: No I don't think there is any way. The only way I know would be to have the serializable take a generic of Integer. But, obviously we can't do that here. So if you KNOW that it wont take anything else, suppressing the waring is the best way. To the best of my knowledge

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
if (savedInstanceState != null &&
        savedInstanceState.containsKey(STATE_SELECTED_CONTACTS)) {
    mSelectedContacts = Sets.newHashSet(savedInstanceState.getIntegerArrayList(STATE_SELECTED_CONTACTS);
} else
    mSelectedContacts = new HashSet<Integer>();
```

and

```
@Override protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
  super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
  outState.putIntegerArrayList(STATE_SELECTED_CONTACTS, Lists.newArrayList(mSelectedContacts);
}
```

but it's little redundant, I recommend to ignore this warning, in this case.
because you know serialized field type is HashSet

Answer (score 2):

When you store something in the Bundle using `putSerializable(String key, Serializable value)` method you lose some information about the type of the data stored, as the method stores any `Serializable` and it doesn't care if it's particular implementation of `Serializable` as i.e `HashSet`. Because the information is lost, there is no way to magically determine in `getSerializable` what type you store. So basically any attempt to avoid the warning caused by explicit casting won't prevent the actual cast from happening.

Answer (score 0):

you could try using an Integer ArrayList an an intermediate:

```
savedInstanceState.putIntegerArrayList(STATE_SELECTED_CONTACTS, new ArrayList<Integer>(mSelectedContacts));
```

and then read it back like this:

```
mSelectedContacts = new HashSet<Integer>(savedInstanceState.getIntegerArrayList(STATE_SELECTED_CONTACTS));
```